# How to convert table to treeview?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to convert table that i get from using php mysql as shown in images below to treeview with checkboxes, what is the best way to do that.

Table
[image: table.png]

to

TreeView
[image: tree.png]

Here is my code:

```
<h4>Select Students</h4>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
 <thead>        
  <tr>
   <th>#</th>
   <th>Class</th>
   <th>Roll/SL No.</th>
   <th>Adm No.</th>
   <th>Student Name</th>
   <th>Father Name</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn7,"SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE school_id='$school_id' order by st_class_name ASC, roll_no + 0 ASC, st_name ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
   <tr>
      <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>"></td>
      <td><?php  echo $row["st_class_name"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php  echo $row["roll_no"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php  echo $row["admission_no"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php  echo $row["st_name"]; ?></td> 
      <td><?php  echo $row["father_name"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

new code that i had tried-

```
<?php
$prev_class_id = 1;
$sql_query_stu = mysqli_query($conn7,"SELECT * FROM student_info where school_uni_id='$school_uni_id' order by st_class ASC, roll_no + 0 ASC, st_name ASC"); 
while($display_stu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query_stu)){
$class_id = $display_stu['st_class'];
$prev_class_id = prev($class_id);
$class_id = $display_stu['st_class_name'];

if($class_id != $prev_class_id){
?>
    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;
        <label>
        <input  id="xnode-0-1" data-id="custom-0-1" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo "$class_id"; ?>"/>
        &nbsp;<?php echo $display_stu['st_class_name']; ?>
        </label>
    </li>
<?php }} ?>
```

results-
[mytree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cor1A.png)

class_id and class_name is with every student in my mysql table

Comment: And you want us to code this for you? Or have you tried anything on your own yet? (If so, please paste your code _in the question_ and we'll see what we can do to solve your problem)

Comment: @kerbholz  I had tried so many things but unsuccessful thats why I asked in the question - what is the best way to achieve that.

Comment: "_I had tried so many things_" Can you post at least one of those tries in your question?

Comment: @kerbholz Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: His suggestion was to add the code for any of the many things you tried (preferably the one where you came closest to your goal), and then we can try to fix it. stackoverflow is not a codewriting service, or a service that lists all 18251 alternative solutions to implement this and decides which of those is the best *for you* (which will depend on a lot of other details than just "some working code"). So find some you like, try to implement it, then come back and post a specific problem you have with it (e.g. you may get an error message or an incorrect result).

Comment: @Solarflare i have no idea how to do that, please provide me any suggestion, How to make treeview with same class name.

Comment: You said you tried so many things. We have no clue where you stand, which is another reason why we would like to see what you tried. As the most simple thing to try is https://www.google.com/search?q=treeview+php  and use one of those. We cannot tell you which of those will be *the best for you*.

Comment: @kerbholz I updated my answer, please check the code that I had tried.

Comment: @Solarflare i updated my answer now please check the code that i had tried. You are the best for me.

Comment: It looks like you're using jquery, and a jquery plugin called *hummingbird treeview.* That requires php to put the details into your html, and the use of Javascript, jquery, and hummingbird-preview code to run **in the user's browser** to operate the treeview object. You don't seem to be using ajax.  Do you get anything in the browser, or is it blank? Have you tried View Source... on the html page generated by your php program?  What shows up in the Javascript console in the browser? Is your failure in the php code or client-side in the Javascript code?

Comment: @O.Jones  Javascript working fine the problem is with php code because I am using while loop inside while loop thats making my website slow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what does not work with your solution. If it works correctly but is too slow, explain that in your question. It seems unlikely you'll have a visible slowdown unless you have many thousands of services and students.

Comment: @O.Jones  Yes it works perfectly fine if no of rows is below 1000 , but works very slow if no of rows is above 1000. that why i only want to use 1 table and 1 while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your performance problem is due to nested database queries. You can do this better with a single query containing a JOIN. I must guess at the query because you have not shown your table definitions.

```
SELECT s.sub_cat_id,
       s.sub_cat_name.
       i.roll_no,
       i.st_name,
       i.st_mobile,
       i.st_dob 
  FROM all_services s 
 WHERE s.school_id='$school_id'
  JOIN student_info i ON s.sub_cat_id = i.st_class
 ORDER BY s.sub_cat_name,
          i.roll_no + 0 ASC, 
          st_name ASC;
```

Then your php code needs to do something like this:

```
$previous_class_id = -10000;
$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn7,$the_query_above);
while($display = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_query))
{
   $class_id = $display['sub_cat_id'];

   if ($class_id != $previous_class_id) 
   {
      /* html for the checkboxes, etc for each class */
   }

   /* html for the student details */

   if ($class_id != $previous_class_id) 
   {
      $previous_class_id = $class_id;
      /* html for the ends of lists of students  </ul> </li> and the like */
   }
}
```

The logic about `$previous_class_id` lets you break up the rendering of your result class-by-class.  some languages (`PL/1` for example, look it up -) have an

```
    ON CHANGE $class_id { do something }
```

but in php you have to fake it.

For future reference: It was difficult to guess from your question what your real problem was. It's definitely worth your time to try to formulate questions more exactly.

Comment: please check my updated answer, i think iam very near to my solution

Comment: plz help, i had given my everything but no success.